# Cell Count from given image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am not able to figure out how to count the number of big cells from the following image.
[image]

Comment: What did you try? The more info and details you give the more likely it is that you will get a proper answer.

Comment: His is my code, which gives total number of images not what I need:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the cells of interest look quite circular you can use [imfindcircles](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) in the Lab colorspace, which is more suitable to work with here than the RGB space given the ~purple colors from the H&E staining of the cells.

So basically convert the color space, then apply a threshold on the 3rd channel in which the large cells are the most bright, and then apply `imfindcircles`. Note that here the `Edge` property has to be quite low in order to distinguish cells close to one another (as in the lower left of your image). Moreover, my version of Matlab does not support [rgb2lab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2lab.html?searchHighlight=rgb2lab) so I used [makecform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/rgb2lab.html) to convert between color spaces.

Here is what the 3 channels of the image in the Lab colorspace look like:

[image]

As you see, the large cells with the big nucleus that seemed the brightest stand out quite a lot in the 3rd channel. Thus we will threshold only this channel for the rest.

In order to get the # of detected cells simply ask for the number of `radii` given by the function `imfindcircles` (`numel(radii)`).

```
clear
clc

close all

Im = imread('Cells.jpg');

%// Transform to Lab color space
cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
Im_lab = applycform(Im,cform);

%// Apply threshold
Im_lab = im2bw(Im_lab(:,:,3),.35);

%// Detect ~circles
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(Im_lab,[12 35],'Sensitivity',0.7,'Edge',0.1,'ObjectPolarity','dark');

imshow(Im);
hold on
viscircles(centers, radii,'EdgeColor','k','LineWidth',4);

NumCircles = numel(radii);

%// Display message box
Msg = sprintf('You have just found %i circles!!!\n',NumCircles);

msgbox(Msg)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I am looking for output number of cells along with above.for example it should say number of cells = 7 and display the image. Thanks.

Comment: @ddesai this method will show you the number of cells. Use this line `num_of_cells = size(centers,1);` you will see it prints out the count.  Great code Benoit_11

Comment: thanks @andrew I thought I had written it :) I'll edit the answer to make things clearer